# Accessing SQL DB with only one user?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

i want to design a php server that connects to a database.
I'm thinking of two ways:
first, i can check if the user has is registered and then give him access to the DB using a general username like this:

```
    <?php

    /*
     * database connection variables
     */
    if(username_is_valid()){
       define('DB_USER', "user"); // general db user
       define('DB_PASSWORD', "userpassword"); // db password 
       define('DB_DATABASE', "db_1"); // database name
       define('DB_SERVER', "localhost"); // db server
    }    
?>
```

or i can give every user a unique username and password

**what would be better practice?**

Comment: Why would you give users access to the database?

Comment: i want the client side to be able to retrieve information from the DB

Comment: create functions to do that. never give the user direct access

Comment: Like @James wrote, use mysql queries in combination with php to present data to the users.

Comment: but should i have a specific username for every user that accesses the DB or just let everyone use the same connection parameters?

Comment: Database username and password has nothing to do with user accounts. You have to create account structure using php and sessions. Database username and password is meant only for application to be able to connect and get specific data out of database.

Comment: And if you provide access to the database server directly, you could present them Views only.

Comment: access to a database server directly is for people who need to administrate the database. In companies, even developers sometimes aren't allowed DB access, just a structure plan and a user to access from PHP for their scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical design would have the application access the SQL Server database using a single database account. Tables in the database would store information about the application's users, e.g. username, hashed password, privileges, ... .

The application can use stored procedures in the database to access data. By protecting the tables and granting `execute` access to the application's account for the stored procedures you limit the damage that can be done by the application and anyone else using the application's credentials.

Passing the user's identification to the stored procedures allows them to restrict access appropriately on a per-user basis, e.g. an office manager may be able to change data for everyone in their office.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to give users access to the database, you give PHP access to mysql and use PHP to access data.

So, you have a mysql user assigned in mysql, and you use your PHP code to access mysql using that user. Then once the PHP script has a connection to the database using that mysql user, you can retrieve (insert, update, etc) data from the database and serve it back to the user through PHP/HTML/CSS etc.

> but should i have a specific username for every user that accesses the DB or just let everyone use the same connection parameters?

*Users do not access your mysql*.
Users access your website scripts (PHP in this case), then PHP has access to mysql.

user->website->php script->mysql->retrieve data->show to user

To answer your question however, "PHP" (not users) uses the same mysql user to connect to mysql for every user on your site. Whatever user you serve data to from mysql, PHP can use the same mysql user.
You can use different mysql users, but very rarely, and if you actually needed to, you would know why and already know all this (ie a very large set of scripts/framework etc)